# Usecases for method hiding using new

Tags: c#

This is more or less an exact duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117838/why-do-we-need-the-new-keyword-and-why-is-the-default-behavior-to-hide-and-not-ov), but as I cannot edit it, I started this. Feel free to move something over and close this one.

Using method hiding with new seems like a dangerous feature, and given the discussion in the other thread, it seems it's not only I who have problems finding a valid use case for this. Any methods accepting Base won't use Derived's Method.

```
public class Base
{
    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public new void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived");
    }
}

var derived = new Derived();
derived.Method(); // "Derived"
((Base)derived).Method(); // "Base"
```

So what are some valid use cases for new that is difficult to solve with other features?

Comment: The VB keyword is shadows and is one of the few cases where VB used a more appropriate keyword, imo.

Comment: @marc: I think abstract=MustInherit and sealed=NotInheritable are other good ones.

Comment: To be honest, I really like the shorter versions. It's only the first time you see the words you have to look it up, but programming is not something you don't have to learn even if you understand what the keywords mean without looking them up. I agree new is a bit strange though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why do we need the new keyword and why is the default behavior to hide and not override?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117838/why-do-we-need-the-new-keyword-and-why-is-the-default-behavior-to-hide-and-not-ov)

Comment: Why are a new question about the same topic? If it's a exact duplicate, it should be closed.

Comment: @George: It's not quite the same, but if I could, I would have added it to that post instead.

Comment: @George: Ok, just got a good answer in the other thread, so I voted to close too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to avoid the [*brittle base class*](https://ericlippert.com/category/brittle-base-classes/) problem as far as possible.

Suppose you provide a library, and I derive from one of your classes. I create my own method, `Foo()`, and call it appropriately. Fine.

Now you introduce a second version of your library, and you add the `Foo()` method (with the same signature) to the base class. Now your code will call `Foo()`, which has one particular meaning... and that may be a *completely different* meaning to my `Foo()` method. The default behaviour (and the behaviour if you add the `new` modifier) is for things to behave as they should: code which only knows about the base class will call your method - which is fine, as that's what they mean. Code which uses an expression which has a compile-time type of my derived class will use *my* method - and that's fine, as that's what *they* should mean as well. (Basically it can only be my code, because only my code knows about my class.)

It should *usually* be avoided - it can lead to subtle bugs where changing the compile-time type of the variable silently changes the behaviour... but it's present for that sort of situation. Basically, adding a method to a base class shouldn't break derived classes, as far as possible.