# Enumerable.Distinct - What methods does your custom class have to implement for it to work?

Tags: c#, .net

I've implemented every function that MSDN says is necessary, plus some additional comparison interfaces - nothing seems to work.  Following is code (optimized for LinqPad).
The resulting output is all 4 items, not 2 like I expect.
Please don't post work arounds as answers - I want to know how Distinct works

```
void Main()
{
  List<NameClass> results = new List<NameClass>();
  results.Add(new NameClass("hello"));
  results.Add(new NameClass("hello"));
  results.Add(new NameClass("55"));
  results.Add(new NameClass("55"));
  results.Distinct().Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

  public class NameClass : Object
    , IEquatable<NameClass>
    , IComparer<NameClass>
    , IComparable<NameClass>
    , IEqualityComparer<NameClass>
    , IEqualityComparer
    , IComparable
  {

    public NameClass(string name)
    {
      Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public int Compare(NameClass x, NameClass y)
    {
      return String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
    }

    public int CompareTo(NameClass other)
    {
      return String.Compare(Name, other.Name);
    }

    public bool Equals(NameClass x, NameClass y)
    {
      return (0 == Compare(x, y));
    }

    public bool Equals(NameClass other)
    {
      return (0 == CompareTo(other));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(NameClass obj)
    {
      return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public new int GetHashCode()
    {
      return Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public new bool Equals(object a)
    {
      var x = a as NameClass;
      if (null == x) { return false; }
      return Equals(x);
    }

    public new bool Equals(object a, object b)
    {
      if (null == a && null == b) { return true;  }
      if (null == a && null != b) { return false; }
      if (null != a && null == b) { return false; }
      var x = a as NameClass;
      var y = b as NameClass; 
      if (null == x && null == y) { return true;  }
      if (null == x && null != y) { return false; }
      if (null != x && null == y) { return false; }
      return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
      if (null == obj) { return 0; }
      var x = obj as NameClass;
      if (null != x) { return x.GetHashCode(); }
      return obj.GetHashCode();
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
      if (obj == null) return 1;

      NameClass x = obj as NameClass;
      if (x == null) 
      {
        throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a NameClass");
      }
      return CompareTo(x);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is this `public new int GetHashCode()` line for????

Comment: It's overriding the System.Object.GetHashCode() func, as specified in the MSDN docs.

Comment: `new` does not override but hides the member in the base class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How `Distinct` works:

There is at least no implementation of `Object.GetHashCode()` which is used for initial comparison of objects: basic version of `Distinct` compares (actually puts in dictionary) by `Object.GetHashCode` first, than if hash code matches by `Object.Equals`.

To be precise [Enumerable.Distinct(this IEnumerable source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) uses `EqualityComparer<NameClass>.Default` to finally check for equality (note that if hash codes don't match it will not reach that portion of the comparison which is why your sample does not work).

> The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of the types that implement the IEquatable generic interface.

[EqualityComparer.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) in turn actually allows to use class without `IEquatable<T>` at all falling back directly to `Object.Equals`:

> The Default property checks whether type T implements the System.IEquatable interface and, if so, returns an EqualityComparer that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it returns an EqualityComparer that uses the overrides of Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T.

So for basic `Distinct` to work you just need correct version of `Equals`/`GetHashCode`. `IEquatable` is optional, but must match behavior of `GetHashCode` in the class.

---

How to fix:

Your sample have `public new int GetHashCode()` method, which likely should be `public override int GetHashCode()` (Same for `Equals`).

Note that `public new int...` does not mean "override", but instead "create new version of the method that hides old one". It does not impact callers that call method via pointer to parent object.

Personally I think `new` should rarely be used in defining methods. Some suggestions when it is useful are covered in [Usecases for method hiding using new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118372/usecases-for-method-hiding-using-new).

Comment: I hate override and new - so two functions need to be marked override, but one function should be marked new                     public override int GetHashCode()
    {
      return Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object a)
    {
      var x = a as NameClass;
      if (null == x) { return false; }
      return Equals(x);
    }

    public new bool Equals(object a, object b)
    {
    }

Comment: The MSDN documentation is very misleading - it suggests that as long as the class implements IEquatable<>, then that interface will be used.

Comment: Technically `Distinct` uses `EqualityComparer<NameClass>.Default;`.

Comment: @Drew, it is indeed used, there's nothing misleading in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the order of operations here. GetHashCode is called first and Equals as a backup. I've been trying to figure out why Equals was not called and this was the first post of 20 that called this point.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to implement any interface, just `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods correctly:

```
public class NameClass
{
    public NameClass(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as NameClass;
        return other != null && other.Name == this.Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Enumerable.Distinct<TSource> Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx):

> It uses the default equality comparer, [Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx), to compare values.

[EqualityComparer.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx):

> The [Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) property checks whether type *T* implements the System.IEquatable<T> interface and, if so, returns an EqualityComparer<T> that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it returns an EqualityComparer<T> that uses the overrides of Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by *T*.

[IEquatable<T> Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx):

> If you implement IEquatable<T>, you should also override the base class implementations of [Object.Equals(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) and [GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) so that their behavior is consistent with that of the IEquatable<T>.Equals method.

[Overriding methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx):

> The **override** modifier is required to extend or modify the abstract or virtual implementation of an inherited method, property, indexer, or event.

So your code should look like this:

```
public class NameClass : IEquatable<NameClass>
{
    public NameClass(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    // implement IEquatable<NameClass>
    public bool Equals(NameClass other)
    {
        return (other != null) && (Name == other.Name);
    }

    // override Object.Equals(Object)
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as NameClass);
    }

    // override Object.GetHashCode()
    public override GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the cleanest code, but note that the IEquatable interface is never used - put breakpoints in there and the functions will not get hit.

Comment: @Drew: IEquatable<T>.Equals is used if you override GetHashCode correctly.

Answer (score 1):

So, first off, `Distinct` will, as per it's documentation, use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to compare objects if no custom equality comparer is provided (you provided none).

`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`, as per its documentation, will look to see if the object implements `IEquatable<T>`, if it does it will use that implementation of Equals.

Regardless of whether or not the type implements `IEquatable<T>`, `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` **will use the `object.GetHashCode` method to get the has code of the object**.  `IEquatable<T>`, unfortunately, does not force you to also override the object's `GetHashCode` implementation, and in your case, while you do implement `IEquatable<T>`, **your code does not override the object's `GetHashCode` implementation**.

As a result of this `Distinct` is actually using the proper `Equals` method for your type, but it's using the wrong `GetHashCode` method.  Whenever you're hashing objects and that type has an `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementation that's out of sync problems ensue.  What's happening is that in whatever hash based collection it's sending the two "equal" objects to different buckets, so they never even get to the point where their `Equals` methods are called on each other.  If you happened to get lucky and there was a hash collection and the objects were coincidentally sent to the same bucket, then, since the `Equals` method is what you intended it would actually work, but the odds of that happening are...very low.  (In this specific case, about 2/2147483647, or 
9.3e-10.

While you do provide a `new` `GetHashCode` method in `NameClass`, it is *hiding* the object implementation, not *overriding* it.  If you change your `GetHashCode` implementation to use `override` rather than `new` then your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I messed up my sample code - my class derives from DependencyObject, not Object.  I can't override thew GetHashCode or Equals functions because the DependencyObject class is sealed.

Comment: if `DependencyObject` is sealed then how are you deriving from it?

Comment: The GetHashCode and Equals function are sealed, not the entire class

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.gethashcode.aspx) states quite clearly why you shouldn't override Equals and GetHashCode in a DependencyObject.

Comment: @Drew Given that you shouldn't be defining value equality natively on the `NameClass`, you can define a separate class that implements `IEqualityComparer<NameClass>` and pass that to `Distinct` so that you still get value comparisons.