# same method name in parent and child class?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why do we need the new keyword and why is the default behavior to hide and not override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117838/why-do-we-need-the-new-keyword-and-why-is-the-default-behavior-to-hide-and-not-ov)

I have a parent and a child class. Both have a method with the same name and compiler allow it. I couldn't understand it. Why compiler has not shown an error in child class if parent has a methoed with the same name. I am not using new virtual or override with methods. Kindly help me understanding this why compiler did not shows an error in child class ?

```
 class BaseClass
{

     public string SayHi()
    {

        return ("Hi");

    }

}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{

    public  string SayHi()
    {

        return (base.SayHi() + " from derived");

    }

}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you get a warning.

Answer (score 12):

The base method must be declared as `virtual` if you want to `override` it in a child class:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string SayHi()
    {
        return ("Hi");
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override string SayHi()
    {
        return (base.SayHi() + " from derived");
    }
}
```

If the base method is not declared as virtual you will actually get a compiler warning telling you that you are trying to hide this base method. If this is your intent you need to use the `new` keyword:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public string SayHi()
    {
        return ("Hi");
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new string SayHi()
    {
        return (base.SayHi() + " from derived");
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

To better see the difference between the two take a look at the following examples.

The first one using a base virtual method which is overriden in the child class:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string SayHi()
    {
        return ("Hi");
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override string SayHi()
    {
        return (base.SayHi() + " from derived");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        BaseClass d = new DerivedClass();
        // the child SayHi method is invoked
        Console.WriteLine(d.SayHi()); // prints "Hi from derived"
    }
}
```

The second hiding the base method:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public string SayHi()
    {
        return ("Hi");
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new string SayHi()
    {
        return (base.SayHi() + " from derived");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        BaseClass d = new DerivedClass();
        // the base SayHi method is invoked => no polymorphism
        Console.WriteLine(d.SayHi()); // prints "Hi"
    }
}
```

Comment: He knew that already, he is asking why it doesn't result in a compiler error

Comment: @Tom Knapen, it results in a compiler warning. There is no need to result in an error.

Comment: This explanation describes the problems completely. The OP did not mention having seen the warning.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, thanks for replying but I coldn't understand what will benefit of overridding a method ? If I override my parent class's method will be gone if I do just what I am doing same will happen. Please guide

Comment: @haansi, when you hide the base method, polymorphism no longer applies and it is the base method that is being invoked instead of the derived one. I have updated my answer to provide you 2 examples of that so that you can better understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Since the method is not virtual, there is no problem to have the same name.
Which one is called depends merely on the type of the reference.

```
BaseClass o = new DerivedClass();
o. SayHi();
```

will return "Hi".

If you declare the parent method a `virtual`, then you either have to `override` it in the subclass or make it `new` (which is the default).
If you override it the above code will return "Hi from derived".
If you make it `new` that is the same as if it was not virtual.

Comment: lvanov thanks, can u plz guide what will differene in method overriding and doing what I did ? what I get is in both ways parent class method will be gone ?

Answer (score 0):

It is called [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) hiding. Please read MSDN article on - [Hiding through inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)