# "new" keyword in C# is just for making the warning disappeared, isn't it?

Tags: c#

I accidentally come across this page [new keyword in method signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014295/c-sharp-new-keyword-in-method-signature) and I found that some examples that was given in this post are not accurate (e.g. Second one)

I think the "new" is already there if you don't say "override". The only difference is that you will get a greenline (warrning?) if you don't write either "override" (for virtual method) or "new". You can still choose not to write "new" and it will still work. Am I right in saying this, or am I missing something important?

Comment: This is dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117838/why-do-we-need-the-new-keyword-and-why-is-the-default-behavior-to-hide-and-not-o

Comment: Look at this answer from Eric Lippert http://stackoverflow.com/a/3118480/149190

Comment: with the second I think you mean this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1014309/112407 (not all have the same sort order) that is indeed accurate and highlights why it's a warning. The code might very well do something else that want is expected. compile time types are seldom more important than runtime type  but in this case it is

Comment: Thanks for sharing Eric Lippert's answer.. but I couldn't make it as answer since it's in comment. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it doesn't do anything except hiding that warning.

The warning is only there to make sure you know what you're doing, since hiding is rarely a good idea. But making `override` the default would cause versioning problems if the base class introduces a new virtual method and the derived class happens to have a matching but independent method which now accidentally overrides the inherited method.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it was basically so you could state intent in your code.

So if you want to hide a method in a base class you use the new directive to tell yourself and others, that you did it deliberately. i.e. you didn't add a totally new method with the same name as an existing onne in ignorance.