# Why is the virtual keyword required to allow the type of substution behavior I'm looking for in c#

Tags: c#, frameworks, polymorphism

I'm trying to get a certain type of overriding behavior in c#, I have found that I need to have virtual flag on the function definitions in a base class that I want to override with the derived class. This implies that a class must make the decision that it can be derived in order to accept those derivations at runtime. It also seems like a really easy way to get code that compiles but has strange behaviors (from the point of view of someone who just tries to use "new" without "virtual"). What is the reasoning behind this? I would think a compile time error in the event of an ambiguous call would be far more "safe" -- does allowing the ambiguity allow for well known use cases and patterns?

(below was my initial question -- crossed out due to finding how to override method calls like I needed, but now I'm looking to know why I need to use virtual on the base class)

<s>From my understanding of polymorphism, if I have two classes, parent and child, and those two classes have two different function definitions (but observe the same interface), I should be able to substitute one for the other. Unfortunately, in the example below I find then when I have an object that is declared as parent type and call the getVal function, it calls the parent-type-implementation. When I declare an object of type child and call getVal it calls the child-type-implementation.</s>

This of course means that if I were to have a function that accepted a parent typed variable as an argument it would always call the getval definition from the parent variable; if I has a function that accepted a child type variable I could never call it with a parent type variable, thus no substitution is possible here.

I can only assume that I am missing something obvious. I've tried putting the new keyword on my getVal declaration on the child class and that doesn't do anything. Override presents a compile time error unless I add virtual.

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    parent obj3;
    obj3 = new parent();
    Console.WriteLine(obj3.getVal()); //Prints 1 because it's called with a parent declared variable
    PrintParentVal(obj3); //Prints 1 because the function always has context of a parent declared variable
    //PrintChildVal(obj3); //Compile time error because Parent object cannot be downcast to child
    
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
    
    parent obj;
    obj = new child();
    Console.WriteLine(obj.getVal()); //Prints 1 because it's called with a parent declared variable
    PrintParentVal(obj); //Prints 1 because the function always has context of a parent declared variable
    //PrintChildVal(obj); //Compile time error because Parent object cannot be downcast to child

    Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
    
    child obj2;
    obj2 = new child();
    Console.WriteLine(obj2.getVal()); //Prints 2 because it's called with a child declared variable
    PrintParentVal(obj2); //Prints 1 because the child declared variable gets upcasted to it's base type of parent
    PrintChildVal(obj2); //Prints 2 because the child declared variable is downcasted to child
  }

  private static void PrintParentVal(parent obj){
    Console.WriteLine(obj.getVal()); //Will always print 1
  }

  private static void PrintChildVal(child obj){
    Console.WriteLine(obj.getVal()); //Will always print 1
  }

  public class parent
  {
    public virtual int getVal(){
        return 1;
    }
  }

  public class child: parent
  {
    public override int getVal(){
        return 2;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This might help you to understand: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords

Comment: PS. The behavior generates 'warnings' you can configure visual studio to upgrade specific warnings to errors if it's a concern.

Comment: This is why: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/future-breaking-changes-part-three

Comment: First of all I would argue that presence of `new` method modifier is a big code-smell  and you should not use it in general. Also you comments in code are wrong in regards of the actual execution results.

Comment: As for "why" - because language was designed in this way.

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3118480/2501279) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/814939/2501279) can be interesting.

Comment: First the comment in the code is Wrong check the correct results by run the program .... the rule is so simple if you create parent object then the parent method will execute ... if you create child object the method in child will be executed .... assigned child object to parent reference just limit you to call your child object as a parent interface (meaning it's actually a child, but we deal with it as parent)