# C# Factory Pattern - Base method will always get called

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm wondering why in the following example does the base method always get called even though I'm overriding it when the Factory Pattern "Builder" returns a new instance of the object?

```
interface FactoryInter 
{
    void MakeDetails();

}

class Builder {

    public static Builder getObject(string obj)
    {
        if(obj == "Cont")
        {
            return new Cont();
        }else{
            return new Builder();
        }

    }

    public void MakeDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I will always get called..");
    }

}

class Cont : Builder, FactoryInter {

    public void MakeDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello..");
    }

}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Builder b = new Builder();
        b = Builder.getObject("Cont");

        b.MakeDetails();
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hint : always read your warnings.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814934/why-c-sharp-implements-methods-as-non-virtual-by-default

Answer (score 7):

You do not override it. You are hiding it. Method Cont.MakeDetails() is hiding the base class's MakeDetails method. For more details please see the below example:

```
class Base
{
    public void Hidden()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base!");
    }

    public virtual void Overrideable()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Overridable BASE.");
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public void Hidden()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived");
    }

    public override void Overrideable()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Overrideable DERIVED");
    }
}
```

Now testing them yields these results:

```
var bas = new Base();
var der = new Derived();

bas.Hidden(); //This outputs Base!
der.Hidden(); //This outputs Derived
((Base)der).Hidden(); 
//The above outputs Base! because you are essentially referencing the hidden method!

//Both the below output Overrideable DERIVED 
der.Overrideable();
((Base)der).Overrideable();
```

To override it, mark the base method as virtual and the derived one as override.

Comment: SKleanthous has it spot on.  A more detailed explanation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx)